f2py: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing
i am trying to compile some fortran code:
module date_mod
  implicit none
  private
  public :: Date

  type :: Date
    integer :: year
    integer :: month
    integer :: day
  contains
    procedure :: init
    procedure :: shift_by_months
    procedure :: print_date
  end type Date

contains

  subroutine init(self, y, m, d)
    class(Date), intent(out) :: self
    integer, intent(in) :: y, m, d
    self%year = y
    self%month = m
    self%day = d
  end subroutine init
end module date_mod


and use it in python with f2py:
f2py -c -m date date.f90
However in python I get an error when importing the module:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import date
      3 # Create and use Date object
      4 date_obj = date.Date()

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing date: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

i tried a few other combinations of compilers but i am not getting any progress.

Are you running this on linux or windows?  On Linux, you should use f2py3 not f2py

i am running this on windows, i can compile it into a module, the issue is importing it in python.

Where is the dll and the interface file?  Are they in the same directory as the test program?
